# Keras ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_18

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, neural-network, keras

I am all done, just stuck in training my NN model in KERAS.
Here is my situation.

1. I have a folder, i have 30 CSV files in there , all different name.
2. Now, I am doing classification.
3. Each CSV file (5000,3 after reading in an array dfs as shown below is a single training instance itself, ,so I have 30 training instances for 30 CSVs).
4. The filename is the label, I want to classify. Theses are 3 unique labels, use one hot encoding.
5. I am confused in the input shape and how to reshape my training data dfs in a correct shape.

Note: 30 observations which are CSV files themselves of 5000, 3 dim and filename is the label.

Here is my code and error.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

path = os.getcwd()
file_list = glob.glob(path + '/*.csv')
dfs=np.array([pd.read_csv(fp).values for fp in file_list])

dfs.shape
# (30, 5000, 3)

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
# define class labels

labels = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3])

onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
integer_encoded = labels.reshape(len(labels), 1)
onehot_encoded = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(integer_encoded)

len(onehot_encoded)
print(onehot_encoded)
# 30
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])




model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(24, input_shape=(5000,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))
# compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

# summarize the model
print(model.summary())



# fit the model
model.fit(dfs, onehot_encoded, epochs=50, verbose=2)
```

ERROR:
**ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_10 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (30, 3)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your labels array is of shape `(30,3)`, while your model is expecting it to be `(None, 5000, 3)`. -- Always check the `model.summary()` to understand what is going on with shapes.

The Dense layers work only on the last dimension, leaving all other dimensions untouched. Since your input is `(None, 5000, 3)`, all your Dense layers are transforming only the last dimension and leaving the 5000 untouched.

At some point in the model, you must get rid of the extra dimension so you can match your labels, which are `(None, 3)`.

There are many possibilities, but the best option depends on how you want the model to interpret data.

**Option 1:**

If all the 5000 lines are completely independent and of different nature (and the model shouldn't learn any common behavioer between these lines), you can add a `Flatten()` layer at the beginning of the model, so it will immediately become `(None, 15000)`.

```
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(5000,3))) #first layer in the model
```

**Option 2:**

Now, if the 5000 lines share something in common, and your model should treat them as if they were different samples of equal nature, put the `Flatten()` layer at the end, just before the last `Dense`.

Example:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(24, input_shape=(5000,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8))

#the flatten layer comes here:
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))
```

**Option 3:**

If these lines are forming a sequence (time series), and you want somehow to learn how this sequence evolves, you're probably going to have better results changing your `Dense` layers by `LSTM` layers. All of them, except for the last one, should use `return_sequences = True`.

Example:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(24, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(5000,3)))
model.add(LSTM(8,return_sequences=True))

#here there are many possibilities as well, one of them being just another LSTM layer without return sequences:
model.add(LSTM(3,return_sequences=False))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

I used the activation in a separate layer because the LSTM's usually work better with their default activation, which is 'tanh'.

Comment: I think, you have given me very good information, I was expecting the same. I did the option 1 and it looks fine. I am not sure, how to do the second and third part with their input parameters. I am very much interested in your LSTM idea, yes my data is time dependent. Please can you write that chunk for an make me explain. I would be he most happy man on this planet. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel. This is so good. Yes, definitely I am going to mark this correct.

Just a question, since I am using one CSV file as one training set (5000,3) dimension. This model is understanding this part? I have only 30 instances for training or 30 CSV files. Please review my question once at hit me "yes" in comment. I am just waiting for that. because training can take hours. I want to mark it correct, right now. 

Is there also any option, I can save all these weights and load my model again for testing from that saved file.

Comment: Yes. When your input is shaped like `(30,5000,3)`, you're correct in using `input_shape=(5000,3)`. The model is going to see this: `30 independent sequences`, `5000 time steps in each sequence`, `3 input vars/features for each time step`.